Run the "gather from tabs" firefox extension on chromium to implement javascript
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gather-from-tabs/
I want to run this code on every tab in chrome and give the number on every tab title.
/* Count Words */
(() => { 
  const words = document.body.innerText.split(/\s+/).length;
  document.title = "(" + words + ") " + document.title;
  return words + " " + document.location.href + "\n";
})()


What's your question? You got the code you need, use it where appriopriate, e.g. in userscript.
